# Numerical analysis online video

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, online-resources

Does anyone know a good on-line resource (preferably video) for numerical analysis(At the level of Atkinson or higher)?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp2MdAvk2MY&list=PL6E313980EF23CA6E&index=25

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Nptel Numerical methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqhSmdkqgjQ)

or [Nptel Numerical analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88ys5ZIolSg)

Good Luck